# What methods exist to get the text of a low quality picture?

Tags: images, image-quality, image-editing

I have an image that is really blurred and I wanted to know if there were any method  to get the text of a low quality picture ?

[image]

It comes from [this link](https://i.prcdn.co/img?file=f6412019010100000000001001&page=3&scale=37). This is a page from [this newspaper online](https://www.pressreader.com/france/carto/20190101?fbclid=IwAR3uoyT3y2XWXRc9CJzsInOtwH2Z11qn6nY2HmJg-vtXtHpm0pZCFzJVepw).

Answer (score 6):

A simple, effective and ethical method exists to get the text from THAT specific low quality image: pay the publisher the fee.

Comment: Wish I could up vote this many times.

Comment: And if you politically oppose to this publisher, would you still pay him the 50$ he asks for his image?

Comment: Though I might disagree politically with that publisher... or any publisher... nonetheless they retain their IP rights - if simply disagreeing with someone were to somehow nullify their IP rights, then what value is the very idea? If for example your use-case is sheer politics, or satire, this may be permissible "fair use" in which case my objection disappears. If however, your use involves making a profit, or creating a non-satirical derivative work for commercial use, then you pay the one-time fee and get your task done.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can extract form that image. Too few pixel to work with sorry. Real life isn't like CSI or Blade runner.

Comment: "Enhance." clickity-click. "Enhance." clickity-click.

Answer (score 0):

It's not only low quality, I think it's intentionally selected low resolution to make possible to see the general layout, but not to read the content. So, if you find a way to read it you should also pay to the publisher what he wants. He obviously has stated a price for reading it.

No sharpening cannot restore the text, but the recovery can be based on the fact that it's text and has a certain font and size. In addition the text is written in certain language. That should give some basement to guess which words has been written. I can give a simple example:

[image]

On the top I have two words written in not so high resolution. Those words are Auto and Home.

BTW. Just in case you need higher resolution to recognize common fonts, the used font is Bodoni MT.

The three darker patterns are comparisons with blending mode difference. Auto vs Auto and Home Vs Home of course both give difference = 0, but the average pixel brightness difference is about 50 (or as well 20%) in Auto Vs Home. Maximum would be 255, if there was a negative.

Actually computer vision does the same, but with more developed calculation algorithms. It makes comparisons with all known detectables and decides the most probable cause of the seen blurred patterns. It isn't only in movies or crime investigation tv series, but in real life. For ex. the security provider of a jewelry shop is alarmed as soon as the face recognition machine sees some well known (=police familiar) person walking around. In the same way the police recognizes interesting (=wanted or non-existent) car license plates routinely.

The applications are numerous in science, business, intelligence, surveillance, robotics, weaponry, probably more various than I can imagine. Of course the cost also is astronomic, but those who want the best do not start by asking the price.

Unfortunately I have no guidance to give how ordinary people could get such sophisticated pattern matching software nor does it be capable enough for your case. If you don't find it or it happens to be too ineffective, you can use the alternative reading method which already is suggested by others.

Comment: Number-plate recognition is ubiquitous these days - even supermarkets have it to see how long you've been in their car park & the police/DVLA use it to see if your car is taxed & insured, millions of cars per day, travelling at motorway speeds. That's not really the same as reconstructing text from the tiniest blurred image.

Comment: @Tetsujin maybe the needed computation is lighter for car number plates, but definitely it must be based on pattern matching.

Comment: maybe so - but it's based on starting with an image known to be sufficient for accurate recognition, rather than a random tiny pic. Inaccurate recognition would be a 'national disaster' as this country no longer has any other form of taxation notification physically attached to the vehicle, it is done entirely by remote recognition cameras, millions of them around the country, like speed cameras [though not the same devices].

Comment: Pattern matching or not, blurred or not. You can not extract info below the nyquist rate.

Comment: @jooja Not true! The info symbol rate can be radically lower, so aliasing the carrier signal doesn't necessarily remove it. An exact constructive proof: Let's have a sinewave, say 1 kHz, Then let's have an alternative signal = full silence. Let the transmitted signal be allways one of these and the signal sender  selects which is valid in each second GMT. Let the signal be sampled with Fs=900Hz, well below the Nyquist rate.  I believe you could still be able to decide which one has been sent if you know the alternatives.

Comment: Yes, only bacause the other signal does not alias. But in this case we have a too few pixels per letter, even deciphering how many letters there are is a challenge. Its way below the states needed to decipher the value. All the  license plate camera trackers i have worked with were easily human readable. Blur in itself is not a problem.

Comment: @joojaa Not true. Let the other signal be also 1kHz sinewave, but 20dB weaker than the first signal, Or let both be equally strong, but let the other have frequency = 1100Hz. There's one second time to decide from the apparent signal (100Hz or 200Hz) was it 1kHz or 1,1kHz.

Comment: Thats not exactly what nyquist says though, your signal intervall is still not below nyquist. But in yout case it stll wouldnt work you could still make errors. In case of unknown text its not that simple, both things are under nyquist , to say that there is a encoding, you need to know what it is too. In this case the data is way too small and haphazard Your claim is extraordinary and requires extraordinary proof.

Comment: @Joojaa I suspect you haven't kept clear that Information transfer capacity has a measure  by Claude Shannon. There's infinitely that capacity if there's no noise, no matter how much the bandwidth has been limited. Shannon's info has been learned to be calculated also in sampled channels. See for ex. this: http://www.princeton.edu/~yc5/publications/ChannelCap.pdf   I do not claim that I can see that writing is especially different than Egyptian hieroglyphs.

Comment: Yes im know about the shennon teorem nand that nyquist talks about reconstrution due to aliasing of singl samples. But in this particular case its way too low. For one we have a noise source, the original image is a jpeg. Second we do not know how and how it was antialiased and secondly we dont know what font it was using so we dont know how to decode it. SO even in best case scenarios we are talking about  a realy hard problem. I dont see any way to do this. NO matter what. And i have done ai text recognition on stuff that was pretty bad to begin with, but nowhere close to this bad.

Comment: Double the pixel dimesnions and i could probably do it.